# RxJava how to take value of first single to finish?

Tags: rx-java

I have two singles as defined below.

```
Single<User> userSingleA = Single
    .fromCallable(()-> {
            // Function fetching user data from mirror A
            return user;
        });

Single<User> userSingleB = Single
    .fromCallable(()-> {
            // Function fetching user data from mirror B
            return user;
        });
```

Both represent an HTTP GET request to fetch a user object. Only difference is that they are talking to two different mirror servers. I want to somehow combine the two singles such that the final single will have user object returned by which ever mirror is fastest. And it should take the value as soon as one of them delivers and ignore the other.

```
Single<User> userSingle = takeFirstResponse(userSingleA, userSingleB);
```

Is it even possible to do this using RxJava? If yes, then how?

Comment: See [amb()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#ambArray-io.reactivex.SingleSource...-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator you could use is [`amb`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html).

> given two or more source Observables, emit all of the items from only the first of these Observables to emit an item or notification

```
Single<User> userSingle = Single.amb(userSingleA, userSingleB);
```

**Note:** `Single.amb()` is only available in [rx-java2](/questions/tagged/rx-java2), for [rx-java](/questions/tagged/rx-java) you either have to convert the source Singles to Observables

```
Single<User> userSingle = Observable.amb(userSingleA.toObservable(), userSingleB.toObservable)
                                    .toSingle()
```

or use merge

```
Single<User> userSingle = Single.merge(userSingleA, userSingleB)
                                .first()
                                .toSingle()
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to convert single to observable, do amb and convert back to single.